# Kakfa Connect Fetch API

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I am running Confluent Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector for the CDC between PG Databases.I am not able to understand thhe internal functioning of the FETCH API that it uses internally.

Please find the trace logs below :

```
{"debug_level":"TRACE","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,090","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"KafkaConsumer.java", "debug_line":"1289","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Polling for fetches with timeout 1643"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"NetworkClient.java", "debug_line":"884","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Received FETCH response from node 2 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, correlationId=1241): org.apache.kafka.common.requests.FetchResponse@22dbea0b"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"FetchSessionHandler.java", "debug_line":"463","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Node 2 sent an incremental fetch response with throttleTimeMs = 0 for session 94079486 with response=(), implied=(mesh.public.glusr_usr-0)"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"Fetcher.java", "debug_line":"1199","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Added READ_UNCOMMITTED fetch request for partition mesh.public.glusr_usr-0 at position FetchPosition{offset=1139704, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[10.130.0.105:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)], epoch=0}} to node 10.130.0.105:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"FetchSessionHandler.java", "debug_line":"259","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Built incremental fetch (sessionId=94079486, epoch=1056) for node 2. Added (), altered (), removed () out of (mesh.public.glusr_usr-0)"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"Fetcher.java", "debug_line":"266","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Sending READ_UNCOMMITTED IncrementalFetchRequest(toSend=(), toForget=(), implied=(mesh.public.glusr_usr-0)) to broker 10.130.0.105:9092 (id: 2 rack: null)"}
{"debug_level":"TRACE","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"KafkaConsumer.java", "debug_line":"1289","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Polling for fetches with timeout 1143"}
{"debug_level":"DEBUG","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,590","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"NetworkClient.java", "debug_line":"522","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Sending FETCH request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=FETCH, apiVersion=12, clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, correlationId=1242) and timeout 30000 to node 2: {replica_id=-1,max_wait_ms=500,min_bytes=100000,max_bytes=52428800,isolation_level=0,session_id=94079486,session_epoch=1056,topics=[],forgotten_topics_data=[],rack_id=,_tagged_fields={}}"}
{"debug_level":"TRACE","debug_timestamp":"2024-01-10 11:21:29,591","debug_thread":"task-thread-testconnector-0","debug_file":"Fetcher.java", "debug_line":"1180","debug_message":"[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-testconnector-0, groupId=connect-testconnector] Skipping fetch for partition mesh.public.glusr_usr-0 because previous request to 10.130.0.105:9092 (id: 2 rack: null) has not been processed"}
```

Please help in understand does Sink Connector uses a separate thread for calling this fetch API?
And Why am I getting this **Skipping fetch for partition mesh.public.glusr_usr-0 because previous request to 10.130.0.105:9092 (id: 2 rack: null) has not been processed"}**